# Huge Outgoing traffic on windwos azure

Tags: centos6, bandwidth, azure, bandwidth-control, bandwidth-measuring

I have a vm on Windows Azure running centos6 as dev node, and have recently experiencing a huge increase in outgoing traffic.

VM was stopped and after started by 1 day it shows 236.63 GB on outgoing traffic, server not running any applications, only 1 landing page.

need help how to detect what causing the traffic and how to prevent it, since it's reflecting badly on my bill.

Comment: Voing to close. "Hire an admin that knows what he does" is the only viable answer as per site rules. It is obvious the OP is over his head to maintain a secure environment.

Answer (score 1):

To find out which processes are using your bandwidth, try nethogs, e.g. `nethogs eth1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to identify and search for active network connections:

```
lsof -i -P +c 0 +M
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.  In particular, what does the grep command do?

Comment: From grep manual: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep -> -i, --ignore-case. Is not mandatory for the command.

Comment: I'm familiar with grep, and `grep "$1"` doesn't make any sense.  It will probably be interpreted by the shell, and as a regex it doesn't work.  So please explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: My mistake. I admit it. Edited the post and removed "grep" part that did nothing usefull. No positional parameter.